# Defer a function call in Qt

Tags: qt, qt4

I have a function in Qt 4.8 (windows), which has 3 things to do, like this:

```
void f()
{
  //1. Do initialization

  //2. Defer g() for next event (on the same thread) so that it may execute after f() is over

  //3. Call h() which is time consuming
}
```

Now, I am not sure how to implement the 2nd step i.e. how to ensure that `g()` is called after the call to `f()` is complete, on the same thread (but on the different stack). I tried using `QTimer` but if I provide a short time say 10 ms, the function `g()` is called even when `f()` has not completed execution. So, relying on timers does not seem to be a reliable idea. Please help, any ideas are much appreciated.

Comment: What does this mean `on the same thread (but on the different stack)`?

Comment: What prevents you to call `g()` **after** `f()` and not `g()` from `f()`?

Comment: So, I want g() to be called from the next event stack of message loop which means that instead of calling g() at this time, I just want to post an event in message loop and call that later when current event processing is complete. I hope it clarifies the things.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Make `g()` a slot or a `Q_INVOKABLE`. Then use `QMetaObject::invokeMethod(this, "g", Qt::QueuedConnection)`.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, it's needed simply to call g() after f(), but on the next message loop cycle, after all Qt events issued from f() would be processed. In this case I suggest the following trick:

```
f();
QApplication::processEvents();
g();
```